# TrimEnd and strange(?) result

Tags: vb.net, trim

I did this simple test:

```
   Dim arg1 As String = "TestString1"
   Dim arg2 As String = "String1"
   Dim result As String = arg1.TrimEnd(arg2.ToCharArray())
```

Now, results contain "Tes" instead of the expected "Test". Why?

Comment: [String.TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String.TrimEnd);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true):

> The TrimEnd method removes from the current string all trailing characters that are in the trimChars parameter. The trim operation stops when the first character that is not in trimChars is encountered at the end of the string. For example, if the current string is "123abc456xyz789" and trimChars contains the digits from "1" through "9", the TrimEnd method returns "123abc456xyz".

Since the letter "t" is one of the characters that you told it to remove, it is doing so.  It stops when it gets to the "s", since that is not one of the characters that you wanted to remove.

To do what you are aiming for, you could do something like this instead:

```
Dim arg1 As String = "TestString1"
Dim arg2 As String = "String1"
If arg1.EndsWith(arg2) Then
    Dim result As String = arg1.Substring(0, arg1.Length - arg2.Length)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't trim with `arg2` as a whole; it goes through each individual character of `arg2` and trims with it separately:

```
character:        S     t    r  i  n  g  1
indeces in arg1:  4  (3, 5)  2  3  4  5  6
```

Note that `t` has two indeces in `arg1`, `3` and `5`.  Also note that all these indeces are contiguous from the end of the string; if nothing had matched the character at index `4` (`"S"c`), the chain would have been broken, and as a result, `t` would have only matched the character at position `5`.

So if you take out the characters of `arg` at indeces `[3-6]`, what you're left with is just what's at `[0-2]`:

```
Tes
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling [`TrimEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accepts a `params char[]` as input, so the same as this:

```
Dim result As String = "TestString1".TrimEnd("S"c,"t"c,"r"c,"i"c,"n"c,"g"c,"1"c)
```

which removes all of those characters from the end of the string including `t`.

C# (more readable in this case):

```
string result = "TestString1".TrimEnd('S','t','r','i','n','g','1');
```

if you want to remove the whole string from the end of the first string use `IndexOf`+`Substring`:

```
Dim index As Int32 = arg1.IndexOf("String1")
If index >= 0 Then
    Dim result As String = arg1.Substring(0, index) ' Test
End If
```